# How to apply "Approve as Baseline" in Azure Vulnerability Assessment using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, security

I want to apply "Approve as Baseline" in all my ID's[Like VA1258] using powershell, so that I do not have to do it manually.

Is there any way to do this.

Below screenshot attached. I want to enable "Approve as Baseline" using powershell.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Set-AzSqlDatabaseVulnerabilityAssessmentRuleBaseline` in Powershell.

```
    Set-AzSqlDatabaseVulnerabilityAssessmentRuleBaseline
   [-ServerName] <String>
   [-DatabaseName] <String>
   [-InputObject <VulnerabilityAssessmentRuleBaselineModel>]
   -BaselineResult <String[][]>
   -RuleId <String>
   [-RuleAppliesToMaster]
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

[image]

Note: `BaselineResult` shows bellow.
[image]

For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/set-azsqldatabasevulnerabilityassessmentrulebaseline?view=azps-4.4.0).

Comment: Hi Pamela, Thank you for the response. In this how to provide the ServerName and Database Name.  I think this does not work in Azure. Got below error while running for Azure Databases. "New-SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaseline : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter 
name 'ResourceGroupName'."

Comment: @Baxy SqlVulnerabilityAssessmentBaseline is used for the local database. For Azure SQL, AzSqlDatabaseVulnerabilityAssessmentRuleBaseline works well. I edit my answer, and it works. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Terraform, this would be the [azurerm_mssql_database_vulnerability_assessment_rule_baseline](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database_vulnerability_assessment_rule_baseline) resource with a valid `baseline_result` block and valid `rule_id`. For example:

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_database_vulnerability_assessment_rule_baseline" 
"example" {
  server_vulnerability_assessment_id = azurerm_mssql_server_vulnerability_assessment.example.id
  database_name                      = azurerm_sql_database.example.name
  rule_id                            = "VA2065"
  baseline_name                      = "master"
  baseline_result {
    result = [
      "allowedip1",
      "123.123.123.123",
      "123.123.123.123"
    ]
  }
  baseline_result {
    result = [
      "allowedip2",
      "255.255.255.255",
      "255.255.255.255"
    ]
  }
}
```